# UITableViewCell expand and collapse

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //case 1
 //The user is selecting the cell which is currently expanded
 //we want to minimize it back
 if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
 {
    selectedIndex = -1;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    return;
}

//case 2 
//First we check if a cell is already expanded.
//If it is we want to minimize make sure it is reloaded to minimize it back
if(selectedIndex >= 0)
{
    NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];        
}


//case 3
//Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expand
selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

Notice how case 1 and case 2 are related collpasing already expanded row where as case 3 is about expanding the unexpanded row.

Both the expand and collapse use the same function of reloadRowsAtIndexPaths function.

**The question for me is that a toggle button, when it's expanded, run that function again will collapse and when it's collapsed, it will expand??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will happen is that when you call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` the table view will reload those rows by calling your implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in your `UITableViewDataSource`. It is up to you to return a cell there which uses the `selectedIndex` variable to decide if it should appear expanded or collapsed (whatever that means for your specific application). It will also call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on your `UITableViewDelegate` (yes, it is silly that this is in the delegate) so if your cell height changes this method too should return a value depending on `selectedIndex`.

Also, I would suggest you only call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` once, like this:

```
NSMutableArray* rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
// Case 2
if(selectedIndex >= 0)
{
    NSIndexPath* previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
    [rows addObject:previousPath];
}
// Case 3
selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[rows addObject:indexPath];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```