# Show UITableViewCell which can then expand to show more data

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell which is currently cluttered and has too much information on the screen at once. I want to make a button, that when pushed, a small view will slide down and show the remaining information, and then when pushed again it will slide back to the original size. I was wondering how I go about doing something like this. I know NOTHING about doing this, so please be specific when pointing me in a certain direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want single Button for all cells in table view or you want to add button as subview on each cell

1.if you want to add button as subview on each cell

a) Add button with tag value equals to `indexPath.row` and set target to single method for each button.

ex

```
 -(void)infoButonTapped:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Now on Click on button find the tag value of button and get the info from the array which you use to populate `UITableViewCell`s.

b) Now create a infoview and add textview on it and set info as text prop of text view and add infoview as subview of view using `UIView` Animation and hide on next click

you can either use a bool variable in .h file to know hide or show infoView or you can check if infoview has superview then you have to hide infoview else add infoview as subview of self.view.

1. if you want a common button for all Cell

a) Now on click of button get `indexPath` for selected cell of tableview using tableview method

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow;
```

this method either return indexpath for selected cell or nil in case no cell selected

Use indexpath for get info from the array and add infoview as subview to view using step 1.b explained above.

you can also get the rect of selected row for setting the cordinate for the info view
by method of tableview

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: This all makes perfect sense, I just don't know how to embed my "infoView" within the cell, nor do I understand how to animate it. Do I just instantiate the "infoView" when the button is clicked? How do I know what coordinates to put for the Frame and what not? Thanks!

Comment: 1. you just instantiate a UIView's object and populate it with required info using controls like textview or label etc and add that view to your view controller view not on cell

Comment: this link will give you idea about uiview animation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628493/using-uiview-animated

Comment: if you do some calculations using table view methods then you can find the desired frame for the info view. 1) you find the visible rows with  tableview's method indexPathsForVisibleRows 2) you know the index path for the selected cell then find the diff between the first visible row and the selected row and as you also know the height for cell you can easily calculate the starting x,y cordinate for the info view

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you better use the following method: -

```
(void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation{
}
```

Make a call to above method in your `UITableView` `didselectRowAtIndexPath` method.

More explanation is given in below link

> [UITableViewCell expand and collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985746/uitableviewcell-expand-and-collapse)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you [Show hide table](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139)

Or you can use BOOL as a property of cell and hide the subviews of UITableViewCell according to bool also resize frame of cell.